# Linearizing systems about critical points.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\def\q{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\p{\end{pmatrix}}\def\l{\lambda}\def\f{\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}}$$

> Find all the critical points of the following systems and derive the linearised system about each
>   critical point. Use this to determine the nature of the critical points and whether they are stable
>   or unstable.
>
> What about say:
>   $$\q y_1' \\ y_2'\p = \q 2y_1 + y_2\\ -5y_1 + 5 \p$$
>
> Here I have a form I haven't before worked with, being that I can't just look at the eigenvalues to find type of critical point, since I can't put it in the form $\vec{y'} = A\vec{y}$ where $A$ is some coefficient matrix. What do I do here?

Form I have worked with

$$\vec{y'} = \q 2 & 1 \\ -5 & 5 \p \q y_1 \\ y_2 \p$$

$$\q 2-\l &1 \\-5&5-\l \p = 0$$

$$=(2-\l)(5-\l)+5 = 0$$
$$=\l -7\l + 15 = 0$$
$$=\frac{7 \pm \sqrt{(-7)^2 - 60}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{7\pm \sqrt{11}i}{2}$$
$$\l =3.5 \pm \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$$
$$\l=3.5 + \f, \l = 3.5 - \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$$

Since we have complex conjugate eigenvalues with non-zero real part, we know this is a spiral critical point at the origin. I could then sub in a few vectors to determine if it was asymptotically un/stable.

Comment: The system doesn't even make sense as it's written, since you are equating a $2 \times 1$ matrix with a $2 \times 2$ matrix...

Comment: @HansLundmark What is your opinion on $A\vec{x} = b$ then...?

These are coupled first order ODEs, where $y_2 = y_1'$

Comment: In the equation $A\vec{x} = b$, both sides are $2 \times 1$ matrices!

Comment: What I was trying to say is the right-hand side should be the $2 \times 1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2y_1+y_2 \\ -5y_1+5 \end{pmatrix}$ (at least that's what I assume that you mean), not a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is $y'=Ay+u$, where $A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -5 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $u = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}$.

The critical points are where $y'=0$, this gives $y^* = -A^{-1} u = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$.

The linearised system can be written as $(\upsilon+y^*)' = \upsilon' = A(\upsilon+y^*) +u = A \upsilon$.

Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1 \pm 2 i$, it is clear that the linearised system is unstable.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will just absorb it now and will get back to you.